# Kafka Server on Static IP instead of localhost

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I currently can produce and consume messages on my local machine. I want to change it so that 1 machine has zookeeper, the broker, and the producer and another machine has the consumer. What server properties do I need to adjust to make this work?

In server-properties, I tried uncommenting `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092`, setting `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://< machineA's static IP >:9092`, as well as changing `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181` to `zookeeper.connect=< Machine A's static IP >:9092`.

However, none of above have worked so far. Any guidance in the right direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> setting `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://< machineA's static IP >:9092`, as well as changing `zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181` to ***zookeeper.connect=< Machine A's static IP >:9092***

The `zookeeper.connect` should point to zookeeper port and not the kafka broker port. So, it should be 
`zookeeper.connect=<Machine A's static IP>:2181`

> Specifies the ZooKeeper connection string in the form hostname:port
>   where host and port are the host and port of a ZooKeeper server

[Broker configurations reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/broker-configs.html#zookeeper.connect)

Also, ensure that your firewall isn't restricting access to your consumer on the broker port (9092). If it is linux and you are using iptables, you may want to allow that port.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9092 -j ACCEPT
```